# Heap Sort ,index of array starting 1 instead of 0

Tags: c, heap, heapsort

```
#include<stdio.h>

int swap(int *a,int *b){

int tmp;

 tmp=*a;
*a=*b;
*b=tmp;

}

void heapify(int a[],int n,int i){

int largest =i;
int left=2*i+1;
int right=2*i+2;

while(left<=n&&a[left]>a[largest]){
    largest=left;
 }

while(right<=n&&a[right]>a[largest]){
    largest=right;
 }

if(largest!=i){
swap(&a[largest],&a[i]);
heapify(a,n,largest);
 }

}

int heapSort(int a[],int n){

int i;

for(i=n/2-1;i>=0;i--){
  heapify(a,n,i);
 }

for(i=n;i>=0;i--){
    swap(&a[0],&a[i]);
    heapify(a,n,0);

 }

}

 void printlist(int A[],int len){

int i;

for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    printf(" %d",A[i]);
 }
 printf("\n");
}

int main(){


int a[]={1,5,4,6,3,9,7};
int len=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

printf("before :");
printlist(a,len);
heapSort(a,len-1);
printf("after:");
printlist(a,len);

}
```

Since index of array in heapsort starting 1,i have manually changed it to 0 by changing value of i,left,right....

But the problems still occurs

Here is the output:
before : 1 5 4 6 3 9 7
after: 9 7 6 4 5 3 1

There must be some mistakes i didn't noticed,thanks for helping!!

ps:Could anyone suggest a cool link,that cant spot the bug or mistake of code,it will be nice.

Comment: You say that the problem still occurs, but you don't say what the problem is. What is your question?

Comment: The output is still not in a sorted list,but i couldn't find out,where is the mistake.

Comment: the posted code contains two major problems.  Both problems are due to being able to exit a function, the is not a 'void' function but failing to return a known value. Those functions are: `swap()` and `heapSort()`.  Therefore, the posted code contains undefined behavior.  Please correct these problems

Comment: OT: regarding: `int swap( int *a, int *b )`  all the calls to `swap()` do not use the returned value, so this signature should be: `void swap( int *a, int *b )`

Comment: OT: regarding `int heapSort(int a[],int n)`  None of the code that calls this function uses the returned value.  So the function signature should be: `void  heapSort(int a[],int n)`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `int len=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);`  the value in the variable `len` will never be less than 0.  Therefore, much better to use `size_t` and modify all references to that variable to expect a `size_t` rather than a `int`

Comment: You stated: *Could anyone suggest a cool link,that cant spot the bug or mistake of code,it will be nice*  [heapsort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heap-sort/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for(i=n;i>=0;i--){
    swap(&a[0],&a[i]);
    heapify(a,n,0);

}
```

The call to `heapify` is still using the entire heap. You need to change that to `heapify(a, i-1, 0)`.

Also, in your `heapify` function, you have:

```
while(left<=n&&a[left]>a[largest]){
    largest=left;
 }

while(right<=n&&a[right]>a[largest]){
    largest=right;
 }
```

There's no need for these to be `while` statements, because the loop body will never execute more than once. For example if in the first one the body is executed, then `largest == left`, and there's no way that `a[left] > a[largest]` will evaluate to true the next time around. Those can both be `if` statements.

Comment: Length of array 7,after len -1 ,which is 6, I am starting the heapify according to array=[1,5,4,6,3,9,7] at i=n/2-1 , which is i=2, because it is last node with 2 childrens ,if i am not mistaken  suppose heapify start from i=2?

Comment: @JohnTang My initial answer was in error. Please re-read now, after I updated it.

Comment: Now i know where is the mistake. I have modified my code and re-run and it works perfectly, Thanks a lot for your help !